# using printf to output floats in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to output a float with

```
printf(theFloat);
```

However, this gives me the following error.

> "argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type
>   "const char *""

I'm not sure why this isn't working, I have had a look and found people using `printf` to format floats... Is there another print method for floats etc?

Comment: Have a look at [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Just because you want to "using printf to output floats" does not mean that you can simply cram a `float` into a `printf` like that and expect it to somehow work. What documents did you read on `printf`? What examples did you look through? I'd say that a single example is typically enough to figure out how to use `printf` for a simple task like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong `printf(char* format,...);`

```
printf("%f",theFloat);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should read the documentation of `printf`. The following prints a single float:

```
  printf ("%f", theFloat);
```

The first parameter should be a formatting string, which is `const char *` (This is why you  got that compile error);

In C++, you can use:

```
std::cout << theFloat <<std::endl;
```

If you want to output the float number with fixed precision, take a look at `setprecision` and `fixed`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
printf("%f",theFloat);
```

You can also add some options for the number of digits to print out on each side of the decimal point. Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)